# Is the serie‎s $‎f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{1+n^2}-\frac1{(n+x)^2+1}‎$‎ uniformly convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Consider the series

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left (\frac1{1+n^2}-\frac1{(n+x)^2+1}\right)$$

Is the series uniformly convergent on $(1,\infty)$?

Comment: Hi.Check the convergence of this functional series‎$‎f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{‎n‎}‎‎\frac{1}{k^2+1}‎‎‎-‎\frac{1}{(k+x)^2+1}‎‎‎$ ‎so ‎‎
‎$‎f(x)=‎lim‎_{n‎\rightarrow‎\infty‎‎}‎f_n(x)‎=‎‎\sum_{k=1}^{‎‎\infty‎‎}‎‎\frac{1}{k^2+1}‎‎‎-‎\frac{1}{(k+x)^2+1}‎$ ‎‎.‎‎‎‎$‎‎\forall x‎ ‎\in ‎‎\mathbf{R}‎‎‎$‎
‎

Answer (score 0):

Hint: your terms are positive since $$\frac{1}{n^2+1} > \frac{1}{(n+x)^2+1}$$ given that $x>1.$ So, perhaps you could make a comparison between your terms and some common convergent series (that doesn't depend on $x$, of course) and use the Weierstrass M-test.